# Ruby on Rails: Delayed Jobs Extend time between jobs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

Is there a way to increase the time in between each job in the queue
I am sending emails so I want each email to send a few seconds apart and not send them right after each other such as the way delayed_job executes the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing there is an option for that, but you could use the "run_at" argument: save the time when you create a job, and when you create the next, pull that number out, add whatever delay you want, and run your job at that time (updating the "last_run" again):

```
last_run_at = ... # collect the last job time
run_at = last_run_at + 60000 #supposing time in ms
Job.create(:payload_object => object, :priority => priority,
    :run_at => run_at)
```